# Renaming a file not during copy not copying to a directory

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following to copy/move files into archive folders.

It will later be adapted to pull down ISS logs and extended to zip them.

My problem is that:

```
Copy-Item $Somefile –Destination $SomeLocation
```

Results in the file being renamed during the copy in place of the directory I would like to copy it into.

I have added some Test-Path Statements to make directories for me but I understand that PS should be be able to do that maybe with an extra switch or definition?

```
#Declare Source and Destination
$Dest   = $env:USERPROFILE+"\Desktop\H drive"
$SourceLocation = “H:”

ForEach ($SourceSubDir In Get-ChildItem $SourceLocation -Directory){

        #Various Sub Directories Transposed to Destination
        $DestSubDir = $SourceSubDir.Fullname.Replace($SourceLocation, $Dest)

        #Create a Filtered List of Files
        $TargetFiles = Get-ChildItem $SourceSubDir.FullName  

        #Loop Through and Move Filtered Files
        ForEach($File In $TargetFiles){
            $LastMonth = $((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1))
            $DateModifiedDir = $($DestSubDir+'\'+$LastMonth.ToString('yyyy\,M')+'Archive')



            If($File.LastWriteTime.Month -eq $LastMonth.Month){

                #Create Subdirectory if not Existant
                If(-Not(Test-Path $DestSubDir)){
                   New-Item $DestSubDir -ItemType Directory
                }


                #Create Date Modified Subdirectory if not Existant
                If(-Not(Test-Path $DateModifiedDir)){
                    New-Item $DateModifiedDir -ItemType Directory
                }


                Copy-Item $File.FullName –Destination $DateModifiedDir -WhatIf
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the destination is a folder: always append a trailing backslash to prevent the copied item from being renamed in case the destination folder is missing.

```
$dst = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\H drive"
$src = "H:"

Get-ChildItem $src | Copy-Item -Destination "$dst\"
```

However, looking at your script wouldn't [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) be a better choice for this task?

```
$src   = 'H:\'
$dst   = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\H drive\{0:yyyy,MM}" -f $now.AddMonths(-1)

$now   = Get-Date
$start = $now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyyMM01")
$end   = $now.AddDays(-($now.Day)).ToString("yyyyMMdd")

& robocopy $src $dst /s /maxage:$start /minage:$end
```

Comment: Thank you,  I'll give this a try at work.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I guess I should read forums on robocopy vs move-item.  This is my first scripting job so probably has plenty of issues.

Comment: Unfortunatly this produces the following:
`Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\craig.chamberlain\Desktop\Archive Docs\Server-02\2014,11Archive\'.
At line:60 char:21
+             $File | Copy-Item -Destination "$DestPath\"
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand`

Comment: Also tried "$DestPath\$($File.Name)" from [technet](http://goo.gl/7LvW6g)  
`Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\craig.chamberlain\Desktop\Archive Docs\Server-02\2014,11Archive\upycling-inscription-form-docx_en.docx'.
At line:60 char:21
+             $File | Copy-Item -Destination "$DestPath\$($File.Name)"
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand`

Comment: @user3822155 `Copy-Item` expects that the destination folder already exists. If it doesn't you need to create it first.

Comment: That makes some sense.  Thanks @ansgar-wiechers I was confused by the docs as in the example 3:  
`-------------------------- EXAMPLE 3 --------------------------
    
    PS C:\>Copy-Item C:\Logfiles -Destination C:\Drawings\Logs -Recurse
    
    
    This command copies the contents of the C:\Logfiles directory to the C:\Drawings\Logs directory. It creates the \Logs subdirectory if 
    it does not already exist.`

Comment: @user3822155 Only if the destination path does not have a trailing backslash. However, without the trailing backslash copying multiple items to a non-existing destination will cause the copied item to be created with the destination path, and then replaced with each subsequent copied item.